# FLT_MAX for half floats

Tags: cuda, math.h, half-precision-float

I am using [CUDA with half floats](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__FUNCTIONS.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__FUNCTIONS), or `__half` as they are called in CUDA.

What is the half-float equivalent of `FLT_MAX`?

The `cuda_fp16.h` header does not seem to have a macro that resembles this.

```
$ grep MAX /usr/local/cuda-11.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_fp16.h
$
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed similar macros once before (not in CUDA though) and found some constants in [this C++ fp16 proposal for *short floats*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0192r0.pdf).

The "S" prefix comes from the proposed "short" in short float.

```
// Smallest positive short float
#define SFLT_MIN 5.96046448e-08
// Smallest positive
// normalized short float
#define SFLT_NRM_MIN 6.10351562e-05
// Largest positive short float
#define SFLT_MAX 65504.0
// Smallest positive e
// for which (1.0 + e) != (1.0)
#define SFLT_EPSILON 0.00097656
// Number of digits in mantissa
// (significand + hidden leading 1)
#define SFLT_MANT_DIG 11
// Number of base 10 digits that
// can be represented without change
#define SFLT_DIG 2
// Base of the exponent
#define SFLT_RADIX 2
// Minimum negative integer such that
// HALF_RADIX raised to the power of
// one less than that integer is a
// normalized short float
#define SFLT_MIN_EXP -13
// Maximum positive integer such that
// HALF_RADIX raised to the power of
// one less than that integer is a
// normalized short float
#define SFLT_MAX_EXP 16
// Minimum positive integer such
// that 10 raised to that power is
// a normalized short float
#define SFLT_MIN_10_EXP -4
// Maximum positive integer such
// that 10 raised to that power is
// a normalized short float
#define SFLT_MAX_10_EXP 4
```

You can also find similar constants from the [half.hpp library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/half/).

NOTE: I am not sure what the CUDA compiler supports regarding fp16 literals.  So you might need to convert these to hex reinterpret the bits as __half (NOTE: note convert/cast).

None of this is ideal and if someone can point you to some `cuda_fp16_limits.h` file, then favor that answer over this one.